# Bootstrap modal goes away immediately after appearing

Tags: jquery, html, bootstrap-modal

I am using following jQuery code to trigger the button to show bootstrap modal.
NOTE: i am using same jQuery code to trigger same modal on another page too and its working fine on that page. and i am only using bootstrap.js not bootstrap-modal.js, what could be the possible problem?

```
 <script>

$(function(ready){
    $(".paypal1_form").submit(function( event ) {
        console.log('here');
      $('button.modal2').click();
      setTimeout(function() {
       return true; 
       event.preventDefault();
      }, 2000);

    });
}); 
</script>
```

Following is the code for bootstrap modal

```
<button style="display:none;" type="button" class="btn btn-info btn-lg modal2" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#RedirectModal">Open Modal</button>

    <div id="RedirectModal" class="modal fade" role="dialog"> 
      <div class="modal-dialog"> 

        <!-- Modal content-->
        <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <p style="float:right;color:white;font-size:14px;margin-top:-12px;" class="close" data-dismiss="modal">X</p>
            <!--<h4 class="modal-title">Modal Header</h4>-->
          </div>
          <div class="modal-body"> 
            <h3 style="color:white;">We are now redirecting you to Paypal...</h3>

         </div>
          <div class="modal-footer">
            <!--<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>-->
          </div>
        </div>

      </div>
    </div>
```

Comment: What's `return true; event.preventDefault();` suppose to do exactly? How can `event.preventDefault();` be called **after** `return true;`, and from inside a timeout no less

Comment: yeah, just need return true. but that does't solve my problem.

Comment: Are you submitting a form? Maybe that's the reason. Try putting `event.preventDefault();` outside the setTimeout callback function (Which I still not completely sure I understand)

Comment: can you please describe what exactly are you trying to do? is it to postpone the submit for 2 seconds?

Comment: i tried event.preventDefault(); outsite setTimeout but did't work.

Comment: there is a form which will redirect users to paypal so i want to show a dialogue for 2 sec with message that now we are redirecting you to paypal so on form submit this function is called.

Answer (score 0):

It worked when i put the jQuery code at the end of HTML code.